# Symfony Bundle with different texts for different languages

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create Symfony bundle, that going to save different texts/flags etc. for different languages.

Is possible (and correct) use Symfony translator somehow for this feature?
Or it just will be two tables?

Comment: why you shouldn't use symfony's translator to translate text?

Comment: I dont want do pure translation. If i will do for example ArticleBundle with this feature, I want in administration set for cz - flag active, text - we are cool vs for en - flag inactive, text - they are bad

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if I understand the question correctly.

But for different texts in different languages, just use the **Translation component**: http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

Basically, you create two files - *mytranslation.en.yml* and *mytranslation.cs.yml* (for English and Czech). Each of them has the same translation keys, for instance:

```
app.title: My English title
app.description: This is my English translation.
app.counter: You have been here %count% times so far.
```

Then, in a controller or a service, use the Translation service like this:

```
$title = $this->get('translator')->trans('app.title', [], 'mytranslation');
```

Or with a parameter:

```
$counter = $this->get('translator')->trans('app.counter', ['%counter%' => 2], 'mytranslation');
```

In a Twig template, you can do the same like this:

```
{% trans_default_domain "mytranslation" %}
{{ 'app.title'|trans }}
{{ 'app.counter'|trans({'%counter%': 2}) }}
```